# Why is my Win10 VirtualBox machine so slow?

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, ssd, virtual-machine, performance

I'm running a Windows 10 guest in VirtualBox, and I'm having a hard time understanding why it's so incredibly slow to run. I'm allocating 2 virtual cores to it, 4 gigabytes of my RAM (in a 16 gig host), and provided a 50 gigabyte fixed size virtual disk image file running on a 3,500 MB/s Samsung 500 gigabyte SSD. Yet it takes a huge amount of time to boot, and sometimes it doesn't boot at all, and just freezes (at least I don't wait around for a long time). The mouse is also really unresponsive to the machine. I just don't know what else I have to take into consideration here

Comment: Try 1 CPU .   A VM should not use all the resources of the host - that will slow both down. Try 3 GB of memory.  I have 3 VMs running here on a fast SSD with resources properly allocated and machines are very fast.  VMware V16.

Comment: How much RAM does your host machine have?  Do you have VB tools installed on the guest machine?  Are you sure the Win 10 installation is good?  Try creating another Win 10 install and see if it behaves the same way.

Comment: You don't mention what the host is.  Is it also Windows 10?

Comment: @Keltari 16 gigs on my host. And thank you, I should've tried that sooner. VB Tools made the mouse impeccably responsive to the host

Answer (score -2):

Generally, all operating system installed on virtualbox or on VMware runs slow as compared to the host machine speed. But if you are still facing this issue then check how much RAM is allocated, if host system has 8GB RAM then I would suggest you to only allocate 2-3 GB for Virtual machine. But if RAM is not the issue then update your Virtualbox application because 2GB is also enough for running Windows 10 on Virtualbox.